# NumPy odeint output extra variables

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, odeint

What is the easiest way to save intermediate variables during simulation with `odeint` in Numpy?

For example:

```
def dy(y,t)
    x = np.rand(3,1)
    return y + x.sum()

sim = odeint(dy,0,np.arange(0,1,0.1))
```

What would be the easiest way to save the data stored in `x` during simulation? Ideally at the points specified in the `t` argument passed to `odeint`.

Comment: Can you give an example that's closer to what you're actually trying to do? Ordinarily, intermediate values in calculations can be recovered in post-processing, and, given that `dy` might be evaluated at timesteps other than the ones you request, and that `dy` might be evaluated multiple times for the same time value, getting x from postprocessing is often the best option.

Comment: I am simulating a system of the type x'' = u, where u is a sum of different forces (e.g. u = u1 + u2 + u3). I would like to be able to plot the forces over time along with the state trajectory.

Comment: How expensive is it to calculate u (or u1, u2, u3) in post-processing, given the state y?

Comment: For (mostly my own!) future reference - I found this answer worked best for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46815621/4988601 (I am posting here as this is the better question :)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A handy way to hack odeint, with some caveats, is to wrap your call to odeint in method in a class, with `dy` as another method, and pass `self` as an argument to your `dy` function. For example,

```
class WrapODE(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.y_0 = 0.
        self.L_x = []
        self.timestep = 0
        self.times = np.arange(0., 1., 0.1)

    def run(self):
        self.L_y = odeint(
            self.dy,
            self.y_0, self.times,
            args=(self,))

    @staticmethod
    def dy(y, t, self):
        """"
        Discretized application of dudt

        Watch out! Because this is a staticmethod, as required by odeint, self
        is the third argument
        """
        x = np.random.rand(3,1)
        if t >= self.times[self.timestep]:
            self.timestep += 1
            self.L_x.append(x)
        else:
            self.L_x[-1] = x
        return y + x.sum()
```

To be clear, this is a hack that is prone to pitfalls. For example, unless odeint is doing Euler stepping, dy is going to get called more times than the number of timesteps you specify. To make sure you get one `x` for each `y`, the monkey business in the `if t >= self.times[self.timestep]:` block picks a spot in an array for storing data for each time value from the `times` vector. Your particular application might lead to other crazy problems. Be sure to thoroughly validate this method for your application.

Comment: This answer is good in general. However, for my application, it will be easier to just recompute the internal variables from y (like you suggested) since it is pretty cheap computationally.  Thanks!