# Take Values inside of odeint in python

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

My question is if there's a way to take some values in a function that are not 
integrated in odeint.

Exemple:  if I have a derivative `dy(x)/dt = A*x+ln(x)` and before to get this equation I computed A throught of a intermediate equation like `A = B*D` . I would like to take the A's value  during the process.

More detailed (only exemple):

```
def func(y,t)
    K = y[0]
    B = 3
    A = cos(t**2) + B
    dy/dt = A*t+ln(t)
    return [dy/dt]
```

Can I take A's values of function?

The answer for Josh Karpel

The code is like that:

```
def Reaction(state,t):

  # Integrate Results

  p = state[0]

  T = state[1]

  # function determine enthalpy of system

  f1(T,p) = enthalpy

  # function determine specific volume of system

  f2(T,p) = specific volume

  # function determine heat release by reactions

  f3(T,p,t) = heat release by reactions
```

# Derivatives

```
 dp/dt = f(T,p,enthalpy,specific volume,heat release by reactions)

 dT/dt = f(T,p,enthalpy,specific volume,heat release by reactions)
```

The real code is bigger than that. But, I would like to know if there is a way to store the values of f1 (enthalpy), f2 (specific volume), f3 (heat release) as a vector or tuple during the process of solution of odeint with the same size of p and T.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, there are some solutions in these two questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904202/numpy-odeint-output-extra-variables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812671/extract-values-from-function-used-by-odeint-scipy-python

Comment: Thanks for pointer. More specifically, I think this answer provides an easy (if not necessarily neatest) solution of getting non-state variables out of `odeint`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46815621/4988601

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but it sounds like you need to pass another value to the function you're integrating over. There are two options I can think of:

1. [scipy.integrate.odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html#scipy-integrate-odeint) takes an `args` argument which contains extra arguments to be passed to the integrand function, which could then have signature `y(t, A)`.
2. You could use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to construct a new function which has the argument `A` for the integrand function `y(t, A)` already set.

Comment: You is talking about input arguments. I was talking regarding if there's a way get off integral function with any vectors or values besides integrated values.

Comment: To clarify: you want the result of the integral to be a function Y(A)? [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/) can perform symbolic integrals/derivatives. Alternatively, it seems like you know the values of A - is there any reason you can't simply compute the integral for each value of A you're interested in?

Comment: Thanks by attention Josh. I will clarify more the problem. I am building a code to calculate thermodynamic  behouivor of a reactor. I am working with two differential equations: one to compute pressure and another temperature. However, there some thermodynamic properties that not are solved but I would like return the value to plot in a graph.

Comment: I saw that exist the function 'append' that I can use and I have already tested. But as we know odeint do adaptatives steps during solution yields more steps than the derivatives's result. I would like to Know if there's a way to use 'append' in odeint and this function return a vector with the same size of solution of derivatives.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me what you want the desired output to be. Could you add an example of the desired inputs and outputs to the question?

Comment: I posted your question as answer above.

Comment: I deleted the second question.

Comment: If you're using odeint to solve for T and p as functions of t, why can't you just plug T, p, and t back into f1, f2, and f3 to get their values at those points?

Comment: Because those points not are derivatives. I work with a open source called cantera (a library of thermodynamic properties ) that return the values of f1, f2 and f3. T and p in this case, are arguments that enter inside of Cantera's functions